# Web scraping with Beautiful Soup / find() function gets result = None

Tags: python, function, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to extract a value from a web page yet I'm unable to get the exact values in the find function of beautiful soup.

**Relevant part of the WP HTML code is the following:**

```
<tr class="Celda 1"> 
    <td height="17" width="48%" align="center" class="txt" style="padding: 3px;">21-04-2021</td>
    <td width="52%" align="center" class="txt">19.887700</td>
</tr>
```

I want to extract the number 19.887700, value which changes every day on such web page.
This is the [URL with today's date](https://www.dof.gob.mx/indicadores_detalle.php?cod_tipo_indicador=158&dfecha=21%2F04%2F2021&hfecha=21%2F04%2F2021).

**My current Python code is the following:**

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from datetime import datetime 

def calcular_tipo_cambio(self):
    dia = datetime.now().day
    mes = datetime.now().month
    año = str(datetime.now().year)
    if len(str(dia)) == 1:
        dia = '0' + str(dia)
    if len(str(mes)) == 1:
        dia = '0' + str(mes)
    url = f'https://www.dof.gob.mx/indicadores_detalle.php?cod_tipo_indicador=158' \
          f'&dfecha={dia}%2F{mes}%2F{año}&hfecha={dia}%2F{mes}%2F{año}'
    page = requests.get(url)
    print(page)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
    results = soup.find("tr", {"class": "Celda 1"})
    print(results)
```

In my Python file I am using a dynamic url, since the web page url changes daily depending on the date.

When I print(page) I get `<Response [200]>` so the connection to the web page is done correctly. However when I print(results) I get None.

Any suggestions on how to get the desired result?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: A class name cannot have spaces, so you're really looking for an element that has both the classes `Celda` and `1` - however, `1` is not a valid class name either. It has to start with a letter or an underscore.

Comment: first you could check if you really get HTML which you expect. When I check `page.text.find('Celda')` then it can't find `Celda` in HTML - and it can means you get different HTML - ie. maybe it gives Captcha or warning for bots. OR maybe it uses JAvaScript to add this element. Or maybe it need correct header User-Agent to send correct result

Comment: you assign to wrong value in `dia = '0' + str(mes)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this example how to get data from this page:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    
url = "https://www.dof.gob.mx/indicadores_detalle.php"

query = {
    "cod_tipo_indicador": "158",
    "dfecha": "21/04/2021",
    "hfecha": "21/04/2021",
}
    
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url, params=query).content, "html.parser")
    
for tr in soup.find_all(class_="Celda 1"):
    fecha, valor = [td.get_text(strip=True) for td in tr.find_all("td")]
    print("{:<20} {}".format(fecha, valor))
```

Prints:

```
21-04-2021           19.887700
```

Answer (score 1):

Code works when I correct

```
dia = '0' + str(mes)
```

into

```
mes = '0' + str(mes)
```

So it was only small mistake with variable.

---

**BTW:**

Next time you could display url and copy to browser to see if it gives correct page

```
print(url)
```

You can also check if you really have expected HTML

```
print(page.text.find('Celda'))
```

Or you can save it in file and open it in web browser

```
with open('output.html', 'w') as f:
    f.write(page.text)

import webbrowser
webbrowser.open('output.html') # it should open file in default program/browser
```